# How to make dynamically changing dropdown list in MS Excel?

Tags: excel

I have .xls file with Columns "State" and "City". States can contain "Gujarat" or "Rajasthan" or "Maharashtra" as value.If user select Gujarat, then dropdown list for City column for that particular Row is changed to two values "Ahmedabad", "Baroda".If user select Rajasthan, then dropdown list for that particular Row is changed to two values "Udaipur", "Jaipur".If user select Maharashtra, then dropdown list for that particular Row is changed to two values "Mumbai", "Pune". 
How to do this?

Comment: **Which columns are you using??**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Keep the data validation cells constant, but change what goes into the cell which make up the list. Specifically,

1. Let's say A1 is the cell with the first dropdown, and it uses data validation (list) to pick from cells B1:b5.
2. And A2 is the cell w/ the 2nd dropown, and it uses data validation to pick from cells C1:c5.
3. B1:b5 is your list of top level sections (states), and is static. C1:c5 is the cities, but it is a formula
4. Make a separate list which links all the cities with the states.
5. Then use the Offset function in C1:c5 to change which cities appear, depending on which state has been selected in A1.

Does this make sense? Let me know if you need help with Offset.

Comment: Thanks. But I am new to use exel so don't how to make formula and how to link them. Please give me exact steps to do this.